# Google meet install in Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I like to know can I install **[google meet](https://meet.google.com/)** into Ubuntu like an app.

Now it is working on chrome,but for Ubuntu installation.

I google it and don't find any installation instruction and don't know; does Google provide any installable file for it like hangout for Ubuntu or Windows.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: It's web based, and runs in your browser. It doesn't need to be installed onto your computer.

Comment: @CarlH I think that should qualify as an answer, please post one.

Comment: Google Meet is web based, and runs in your browser. It doesn't need to be installed onto your computer.

Comment: The problem why one would like to have it stand-alone is that it easily happens that you open another webpage during a google meeting and "destroy" accidentally the Google meeting tab in your browser. It is very frequent that you want during a meeting open a webpage like Wikipedia to show to other participants.

Comment: Another possibility: https://webcatalog.app/apps/hangouts-meet/ (I have not tried it yet)

Answer (score 2):

There is an open source project called yakyak which is unofficial Google Hangouts client for Linux, Windows and macOS. It might work  as google meet is formerly known as google hangouts.  If you use snap you should be able to install just with

```
sudo snap install yakyak
```

Comment: he asked for Google Meet which is the successor of Google Hangouts.

Comment: This is actually the best solution. YakYak did it for me, even after the recent internal transition from Hangouts to Meet. Upvoted.

Comment: Tried yakyak, it just loaded buggy, seemingly trying to infinitely re-login.

Answer (score 2):

Best compromise I've found is installing Meet as a Progressive Web App:
https://support.google.com/meet/answer/10708569?hl=en

At least then you can run it as a separate app to your browser.

To install the PWA, Chrome doesn’t need to be your default browser, but Chrome must be open.

1. On your computer, go to meet.google.com.
2. At the top right of your browser, in the URL bar, click Install.
3. The Meet app appears in your app dock.

To open it from the app dock:

1. Click the Meet app.
2. Join or create a meeting.

From a browser on your computer:

1. Go to meet.google.com or a meeting green room.
2. In the browser bar, tap Open app .
3. Select Google Meet and then Open.

Tip: When you join a meeting from a Calendar event, you’re taken to the meeting green room. From the browser bar, open the app.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app (which sadly has to be installed from a downloaded file): https://webcatalog.app/apps/hangouts-meet It loads up a mini-browser to act as google meet, drive, and many others.

As with all apps not from a repository, use at your own risk.